# How can I determine if a Perl hash contains a key mapping to an undefined value?

Tags: perl, hash, key, exists, defined

I need to determine if a Perl hash has a given key, but that key will be mapped to an undef value.  Specifically, the motivation for this is seeing if boolean flags while using `getopt()` with a hash reference passed into it.  I've already searched both this site and google, and `exists()` and `defined()` don't seem to be applicable for the situation, they just see if the value for a given key is undefined, they don't check if the hash actually has the key.  If I  an RTFM here, please point me to the manual that explains this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> exists() and defined() don't seem to be applicable for the situation, they just see if the value for a given key is undefined, they don't check if the hash actually has the key

Incorrect. That is indeed what `defined()` does, but `exists()` does exactly what you want:

```
my %hash = (
    key1 => 'value',
    key2 => undef,
);

foreach my $key (qw(key1 key2 key3))
{
    print "\$hash{$key} exists: " . (exists $hash{$key} ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
    print "\$hash{$key} is defined: " . (defined $hash{$key} ? "yes" : "no") . "\n";
}
```

produces:

```
$hash{key1} exists: yes
$hash{key1} is defined: yes
$hash{key2} exists: yes
$hash{key2} is defined: no
$hash{key3} exists: no
$hash{key3} is defined: no
```

The documentation for these two functions is available at the command-line at `perldoc -f defined` and `perldoc -f exists` (or read the documentation for all methods at `perldoc perlfunc`*). The official web documentation is here:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html

*<sub>Since you specifically mentioned RTFM and you may not be aware of the locations of the Perl documentation, let me also point out that you can get a full index of all the perldocs at `perldoc perl` or at http://perldoc.perl.org.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you are confused about [exists](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html). From the documentation:

> exists EXPR
>
> Given an expression that specifies a
>   hash element or array element, returns
>   true if the specified element in the
>   hash or array has ever been
>   initialized, even if the corresponding
>   value is undefined.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %h = (
    foo => 1,
    bar => undef,
);

for my $k ( qw(foo bar baz) ){
    print $k, "\n" if exists $h{$k} and not defined $h{$k};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

```
 if ( exists $hash{$key} and not defined $hash{$key} ) {
    ...
 }
```